# matlab complex for-loop correlation calcul

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, for-loop, plot

This is the script that I have. It works till the ------ separation. Under I do not get any error from Matlab, but neither do I get a return of bestDx nor bestDy. Please help. (The first part is given just to put you in context)

```
    %%
% Variables after running script Read_eA3_file.m 
%date_time_UTC
%reflectivity
%clutter_mask

%Convert units
dBZ = reflectivity * 0.375 - 30;
dBZ_Mask = clutter_mask * 0.375 - 30;

%Replace clutter values with NaN
weather = NaN(size(dBZ));   %initialise to constant
weather(dBZ>=dBZ_Mask) = dBZ(dBZ>=dBZ_Mask); %copy values when A >= B

%Reduce to range -- those are 384x384 arrays
dBZ_range = dBZ(:,:,1:16);  %16:18 to 16:23 included
weather_range = weather(:,:,1:16); %16:18 to 16:23 included
weather1618 = weather(:,:,1); %16:18 map only
weather1623 = weather(:,:,16); %16:23 map only

% Plot maps
image(imrotate(-weather1618,90));  %of 16:18
image(imrotate(-weather1623,90));  %of 16:23

%Find x,y of strongest dBZ 
%Since the value are all negative. I look for their minimun
[M,I] = min(weather1618(:));  %for 16:18
[I_row, I_col] = ind2sub(size(weather1618),I); %values are 255 and 143
[M2,I2] = min(weather1623(:));  %for 16:23
[I2_row, I2_col] = ind2sub(size(weather1623),I2); %values are 223 and 7

%Calc displacement
%I get a value of 139.7140
max_displ=sqrt((I2_row-I_row)^2+(I2_col-I_col)^2); %between 1618 and 1623

%%
% -----Section below does not work; ONLY RUN the section ABOVE---------

%% Find Dx Dy for max_corr between two maps 
maxCoeff=0;
weather1618Modified = zeros(384,384);   %create weather array for time range
%weather1618Modified(:) = {NaN};      % Matlab cannot mix cell & double

%%
for x = 1:384
    for y = 1:384
        %30 pixel appx. 
        for Dx = -max_displ:30: max_displ 
            for Dy = -max_displ:30: max_displ

                %Limit range of x+Dx and y+Dy to 1:384
                if x+Dx<1 | y+Dy<1 | x+Dx>384 | y+Dy>384
                    continue

                    %weather1618Modified is the forecasted weather1823
                    weather1618Modified(x+Dx,y+Dy) = weather1618(x,y)

                    %Find the best correlation; Is corrcoef the right formula?
                    newCoeff=corrcoef(weather1623,weather1618Modified);
                    if newCoeff>maxCoeff
                        maxCoeff=newCoeff;
                        bestDx=Dx;
                        bestDy=Dy;
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end


%% Calc displacement
bestDispl = sqrt(bestDx^2+bestDy^2);  %bestDispl for a 5 min frame

%Calc speed
speed = bestDispl/time;
```

Comment: From the guidelines: *"Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers"*

Comment: Please use the matlab debugger and try to understand why the variables are never set.

Answer (score 0):

You have to delete the continue statement after the first if (or place it somewhere else).

The continue statement makes the program skip the remaining part of the for-loop and go directly to the next iteration. Therefore bestDx and bestDy will never be set.

Documentation: https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/continue.html